# Grape Rails API causing AASM to run for GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, aasm

Here is my AASM

```
  aasm column: :status do
    state :pre_approval, initial: true
    state :pending
    state :opened
    state :closed

    event :approved do
      transitions from: :pre_approval, to: :pending, guard: :approved?
    end

    event :received, after: Proc.new { set_received_date } do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :opened
    end

    event :complete, after: Proc.new { set_completion_date } do
      transitions from: :opened, to: :closed
    end
  end
```

Here is my new API

```
module ServiceRequests
  class API < Grape::API
    version 'v1', using: :path
    format :json

    resource :companies do
      params do
        requires :company_id, type: Integer, desc: "A Company Id"
      end

      route_param :company_id do
        resource :service_requests do
          get do
            Company.find(params[:company_id]).service_requests
          end
        end
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Here is the error I am receiving:
`AASM::InvalidTransition (Event 'approved' cannot transition from 'pending'):`

I can log into the `rails console` and run `Company.first.service_requests` and it works perfectly and inside the application it runs when I hit the `service_requests_path`, so I'm not sure why this API call is causing issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you must have a `Company` defined with a `service_request` whose state is `pending` yet is receiving another `approved` event. Your state  machine doesn't define what should happen when a pending request is re-approved, though, which is why you're seeing that error message.

Find that company and the source of the event (does `Company.service_requests` fire any?) and you'll have found your problem. I don't think the problem is with your API class itself.

Alternatively, if you're absolutely certain there's no harm in a company's service request being approved multiple times, you could potentially work around the problem by changing the definition of the `approved` event to

```
event :approved do
  transitions from: [:pre_approval, :pending] to: :pending, guard: :approved?
end
```

One final thought: It looks like you have both `approved` (the event) and `approved?` (an accessor) defined as methods on `service_request`. Check to make sure you're not inadvertently advancing the state somewhere by calling `approved` when you really meant to call `approved?`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I had an `approved` attribute on the `ServiceRequest` model which was causing an issue